# jetty-maven-plugin: Logs during startup

Tags: spring, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

When i use the jetty-maven-plugin, there is a point where it says

`[INFO] jetty-9.3.12.v20160915`

and it hangs for a while, followed by a Scanning Elapsed Time. Is there a way to see what Jetty is doing when this is happening? After a while, Spring get initialized and everything is fine. I just want to see what it's doing in order to identify any startup slowdowns and performance improvements to be made.

This is a large Spring MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

The logging is controlled by your application.

Do you have slf4j present in your classpath? 
Then slf4j is used to process logs from Jetty and any other library that uses slf4j.
Look at your chosen slf4j implementation (logback, log4j1, log4j2, java.util.logging, commons-logging, etc..) and configure that logging to output to console.

Configure the logger named `org.eclipse.jetty` to DEBUG level in your chosen slf4j implementation and see the output flow out.

If you don't have slf4j, then Jetty uses standard `StdErrLog` output that writes to `System.err`.

Comment: Thanks, I do have slf4j and and implementation already present, it's logging everything else (just not anything that happens during that step). Maybe I can explcitily add the 2 output classes above to my log4j properties and see what happens.